# Percentage of light radiated by a black body in certain wavelengths

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

I want to calculate the % of light radiated by a blackbody of a certain temperature (arbitrarily 9000K) in certain wavelength boundaries, arbitrarily say 1nm - 100nm.

Is there a formula that gives you the % of radiation emitted between certain wavelengths by a blackbody knowing its temperature?

If you do, could you also provide the formula then please solve an example?

Answer (score 2):

$$B(\lambda, T) =\frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5}\frac{1}{ e^{\frac{hc}{\lambda k_\mathrm B T}} - 1}$$

is Planck's law for the distribution of spectral emissive power (per unit area per unit solid angle) for a blackbody (note: there exist simpler approximations, but these are only valid at certain frequencies, whereas the question seeks generality). For a target wavelength range $[\lambda_1, \lambda_2]$, the fraction of spectral power from radiation whose wavelength falls in that range is:
$$
\frac{\int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} B(\lambda, t)\ \rm d\lambda}{\int_0^\infty B(\lambda, t)\ \rm d\lambda}
$$

where the bounds of the lower integral arise since the wavelength of *any* wave must lie in $(0, \infty)$. Note that since Planck's distribution has no dependence on angle, this will also be the fraction of *total power* emitted per unit area due to radiation of $\lambda \in [\lambda_1, \lambda_2]$ - as you can see by integrating the numerator and denominator with respect to the measure $\cos\theta \ d\Omega$ (cf. the [Stefan-Boltzmann Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law)): you pick up a factor of $\pi$ for each integral, which promptly cancels out.

Comment: I understood what "1" and "2" meant. Thank you for this very easy-to-understand answer with multiple examples provided to help the mentally challenged understand and learn more